# Is it possible to deploy Angular app on IBM Websphere Application Server?

Tags: java, angular, server, websphere

We're using IBM RAD for development and IBM Websphere Application Server as our web app server here at work. Give these constraints, would it still be possible to develop and deploy Angular SPAs?  Like install a Typescript plugin for RAD probably, but how will  you deploy it to WAS if there are no EAR files generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create a web module (if you haven't already) and package the result of the Angular build (the contents of the `dist/` directory, by default in Angular 2) into the root of your web module, so that it can be served as static content. In Eclipse, the contents of the WebContent folder are placed in the root of the war. Then let RAD package up your web module into a war and possibly ear and deploy it.

That web module should have the following in web.xml in your web module, in order to allow deep links to be redirected back to the SPA so the router can route them properly:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also assume that I can no longer use the JDBC resources defined in my WAS server since I no longer have server side controllers/servlets, correct?  So is my only option to use web services as my back end architecture?

Comment: You could still use server-side java resources if you write REST endpoints to access them and make requests to them from the frontend SPA. The specifics of how you achieve that are heavily dependent on what you have now, though.

Comment: Dear Lwestby, I new to angular. In my case I have created a angular app which is running on npm server. Now I want this app to be hosted in websphere 9 server. Please can you tell me steps I need to perform using eclipse to deploy this app in websphere as ear.

Comment: thanks @lwestby, may I know if there's a way to deploy 2 angular project to the same war? I understand right now you put everything directly under webapp, but how to setup if there are 2 projects to serve? say they will be accessed from {root}/patha and {root}/pathb?